# Graph property on INode in dotNetRDF gone in v3?

Tags: dotnetrdf

I am using the Graph property of INode/IUriNode... in my rdf-projects heavily. Since v3 this property seems to be gone?

How can I get the Graph the Node belongs to in dotNetRDF v3?

Before v3., I was using myUriNode.Graph to get the Graph the node belongs to.

Edit: Example for what I am using the Graph property for (this gives me all types ( rfd:type ?type):

```
public static IEnumerable<IUriNode> Types(this IUriNode uriNode)
{
  foreach (Triple t in uriNode.Graph.GetTriplesWithSubjectPredicate(uriNode, uriNode.Graph.CreateUriNode("rdf:type")))
    if (t.Object is IUriNode uriNodeType)
      worklist.Add(uriNodeType);
}
```

I'm actually using this construction (Graph.GetTriples..., Graph.CreateUriNode, ...) quiet often in my projects.

Comment: Can you expand on what you were using the Graph property for? There isn't a direct replacement for the `Graph` property so the answer may depend on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I would also note that the existence of the `Graph` property was a bad design decision resulting from my own misinterpretation of part of the RDF specification when I built the earliest prototypes of dotNetRDF.  Based on years of experience with the technologies, and clarifications made in later revisions of the RDF specifications about the scoping of RDF Terms, or `Node`'s in dotNetRDF parlance, that property never should have existed and the folks like @Kal who now maintain dotNetRDF are quite right to have removed it

Comment: Well, I am not sure about the reasons you removed the Graph property or why it was wrong there in the first place, but from what I understand, a node always exists within a specific graph (thus the CreateUriNode function of the Graph object and the function to Copy a node to a different Graph object). If that changed, that's really bad for me, because all my rdf applications embrace that principle and I'd have to rewrite *A LOT* of code in that case. Is there maybe something to read about that transision to v3 and some best practices to migrate to v3?

Comment: I'm sorry that the change has made it difficult for you to migrate your codebase, but as @RobV says, it does more accurately reflect the standard RDF model as well as alleviating a lot of unecessary node duplication when dealing with multiple graphs. In the example you give I can see how you are using the property, but not why you can't just use an IGraph argument instead. I'm guessing that there is some sort of data binding or event infrastructure that you are using in your application that provides you with just the INode?

Comment: I don't understand how the changes affect the accuracy of reflecting the RDF model. I currently understand, that the Graph property was just removed from the INode (thus effecting the programming principle that an element of a collection shouldn't reference it's collection) and the INode is still tied to a Graph (so we can't create a triple from different Graphs)? Regarding my example: Yes, I could use another parameter for the Graph but then I'd always need to make sure that the INode is from that Graph. Which in my usage is not necessary.